# Apply Catalog Price Rules programmatically

Tags: magento, magento-1.7, catalog, magento-rules

I tried with this:

```
$catalogPriceRule = Mage::getModel(\’catalogrule/rule\’);

$catalogPriceRule->applyAll();
```

But it doesn´t work.

Answer (score 0):

Try Like this

```
Mage::getModel('catalogrule/rule')->applyAllRulesToProduct($productId);
```